# How to Make Archive ShortCode

Tags: shortcode

I checked that there is an shortcode on wordpress.com but it seems there is no build in way of adding the shortcode of archive on wordpress.org site. I know there was one plugin in repo but it's 2 years old with no updates in code.

So let's say if i want to return the archive. following shortcode doesn't work. Is there anything I am missing? Or is there any way to make this work?

```
 function archive{


 return '<?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>';

 }
 add_action('archives', 'archive');
```

Comment: You should avoid generic function names like `archive`. This will cause a fatal error if a plug-in/theme/WordPress defines a function of the same name.

Comment: I see, I'll have to think up about naming conventions from now on.

Comment: If you are using PHP 5.3, look into namespacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a shortcode. Take a look at the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) for examples of how to do this.

Here is your specifc example:

```
function wpse61674_archives_shortcode_cb( $atts ) {
    return wp_get_archives('type=monthly');
}
add_shortcode( 'archives', 'wpse61674_archives_shortcode_cb' );
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I was wrong with add_action function.:)