# How to enable [archives] short code

Tags: widgets, archives

I want to use the `[archives type=yearly]` short code on a side bar widget so that people can click on links and see posts for the year.  But this is the result I'm getting:

[image]

This is what I'm doing in the Widgets Editor:

And I added `add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );` to `wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/functions.php`.

I also get a similar problem when pasting the `[archives]` into a page or post.  The website just renders it at `[archives]`.

If I enter a shortcode like `[gallery]`, I see a gallery.

So the problem is with the `[archives]` short code.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know or understand why, but I pasted this into `wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/functions.php` and it worked:

```
function wpse61674_archives_shortcode_cb( $atts ) {
    return '<h2 class="widget-title">Archives</h2><ul>'.wp_get_archives(array('format'=>'html','echo'=>false,'type'=>'yearly')).'</ul>';
}
add_shortcode( 'archives', 'wpse61674_archives_shortcode_cb' );
```

I found this code somewhere on the internet, but it wasn't part of the wordpress documentation on archives shortcode.

Comment: It appears [WordPress.com has a built-in `[archives]` shortcode](https://wordpress.com/support/archives-shortcode/). However, self-hosted WordPress sites do not. So the snippet you've found uses [`add_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/) to create one.

Comment: "I found this code somewhere on the internet" - the clue's in the function name: [question 61674 here on WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/61676)